Why do most linux distros fail and put me into emergency shell?
I have tried to install both Arch (archinstall and classic method) and NixOS many times. The installer works fine for both, though I had to use the gnome installer for NixOS. I will copy all of my commands off of the internet to a t or just use the installer without changing anything and I still get thrown into an emergency shell. My keyboard doesn't work and I get the errors posted in this image:

I thought I should include my hardware info. I use an intel i7-12700KF and an Nvidia RTX 4060 in a Gigabyte B760M AORUS ELITE AX motherboard with corsair vengeance ddr5 RAM. I use a razer huntsman v2 as my keyboard. I would assume it's some hardware issue but I don't know what. Linux mint works perfectly though.
I've recently found out that the reason might be that my EFI partition is full. I tried reinstalling grub but now it skips the grub menu and just goes straight to linux mint.

It's best you ask on Arch forums. Or you could try some more user friendly distro such as Fedora or Ubuntu.

random guess: Maybe resizable BAR is implemented broken in you motherboard firmware?

Niether of those comments are the issue.  The OP needs to read Section 3.1 of the Arch install handbook and generate the /etc/fstab file correctly.  The linked image indicates that the boot process is failing because NONE OF THE FILES EXIST.  This almost always happens because 1.)The person installing the OS did not create the files in the /boot directory properly. 2) Installed grub in the wrong place, or 3) Advised Grub and the RAM disk to load files from the wrong disk.

I've been using Linux for more than two decades and have installed various distributions, including Arch, which is what I currently use. And I still get it wrong. Arch is a brilliant distro, but installing it isn't the easiest thing even for long time Linux users. The one thing I have learned is that it is absolutely essential to follow the install guide to the letter.  On the bright side, one of the great things about Arch is that you only ever need to install it once on any given hardware and don't need to go through that again to update.
